# Php работа со строками

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Есть строка

```
http://examle.com/primer?product_id=200
```

Можно ли как нибудь взять из нее подстроку 200?
Данное число всегда разное.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте функции [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) и [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)

```
<?php

$str = 'http://examle.com/primer?product_id=200';
$query = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $variables);

var_dump($variables);
```

Результат

```
array (size=1)
   product_id' => string '200' (length=3)
```

Comment: не совсем понял как $variables взять

Comment: @votanko, массив `$variables` создастся после вызова `parse_str` и будет содержать Вас запрос в виде `key => value`.

Answer (score 2):

Если строка всегда такая и будет, только разные значения, то так:

```
$str = 'http://examle.com/primer?product_id=200';
$result = explode('=', $str)[1];
echo $result;
// Выведет: 200
```