# Как прочитать GET параметры если настроены URL в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, api, get, mod-rewrite

У меня есть формирование красивых URL с помощью настроек .htaccess и правила

```
RewriteRule ^uiscom/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? /uiscom.php?api_key=$1 [L]
```

Это формирует такую ссылку

```
https://api.site.ru/uiscom/e9a593b1f90b7fb5f88dd838e5e09eff/
```

Где код это код API для доступа.

Но проблема в том что из телефонии данные приходят GET и нужно их прочесть, т.е. после ключа API прочитать параметры которые приходят.

т.е. ссылка получается такой:

```
https://api.site.ru/uiscom/e9a593b1f90b7fb5f88dd838e5e09eff/?event=incoming_call&start_time=1429796228.8&call_time=2015-04-23+16%3A37%3A08.797&event_timestamp=1429796229&numa=79637501234&numb=74952043093&cdr_id=28008103
```

**Как прочесть параметры GET?**

Comment: Берете строку запроса из `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` и дальше используете функции `parse_url()` и `parse_str()` вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561623/php-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/561625#561625 Или из `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`.

Comment: @Visman а проще решения нет? нельзя ли как-то задать это в  .htaccess чтобы ссылку формировало с ключом API а все остальное читалось?

Comment: решил проблему оказывается просто вместо флага L поставить надо было QSA

Comment: Лучше сделайте флаги `[L,QSA]`, чтобы другие правила не срабатывали после выполнения этого.

Comment: @Visman ну да я так и сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел решение!

Если у вас есть настройки красивых ссылок (ЧПУ) сделаны через правило RewriteRule и есть дополнительные параметры GET, которые нужно прочесть, то в правиле формирования красивой ссылки нужно просто поставить сочетание флагов [L,QSA] все параметры после сформированной ссылки можно быть вывести обычным $_GET.