# Регулярные выражения (get строка)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, get

Добрый день. Помогите написать регулярное выражение чтобы пропускало строки примерно такого вида:

```
match?league=100&home=Реал Мадрид&away=Барселона
```

число в league может быть любым. т.е [0-9]+

Comment: Так может легче проверить масcив $_GET? Или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561625/186083

Comment: Нет, нужно просто регулярное выражение которое пропустит эту строку такого типа. Порядок такой же, просто число и названия команд могут меняться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю что нужно видеть еще другие варианты, чтобы значть что фильтровать.
пока так (php):

```
'/match\?league=\d+?&home=.+?&away=.+/'
```

Но скорее всего вам нужен произвольный порядок параметров, а может быть остальные параметры совсем не важны... Уточните пожалуйста