# Получить данные из строки в корректной кодировке

Tags: php

Есть строка вида `firstName=%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9&lastName=&patronymic=&phone=80004064909`. Как получить корректное значение firstName и phone, например? Это не get-запрос, это строка.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Php работа со строками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561623/php-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Используете только parse_str() без parse_url().

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет. За счет уникальности символов, можно делать

```
$vars = explode("&", $str);
$data = [];
foreach($vars as $var) {
    $elem = explode("=", $var);
    $data[$elem[0]] = $elem[1];
}
```

Таким образом в массиве **$data** будут все переменные и их значения.

**P.S.** Прошу прощения за такой код.

**UPD.** Желательно еще использовать

```
$data[$elem[0]] = urldecode($elem[1]);
```

Если строка закодирована.

Comment: Велосипед не едет -> `["firstName"]=>
  string(42) "%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9"`

Comment: @Visman используйте urldecode();
[вот доки](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: Зачем, если функция parse_str() заменяет весь ваш пример + urldecode()?

Comment: @Visman, Я предложил лишь возможный вариант Решения.